# Laravel Eloquent - relations method is returning HasMany object and property is returning Collection

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent, relational-database

I have a simple questions but I cant find any answer in internet.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function variants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
    }
}

>>> $p->variants();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany {#4331}
>>> $p->variants;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4310
     all: [
       App\Models\Variant {#4319
         id: "1",
         name: "VariantOne",
         created_at: null,
         updated_at: null,
         quantity: "2",
         product_id: "1",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Why while I'm using method `variants()` I got empty `HasMany` object but when I use just a `variants` property, I got a `Collection` with properly data?

And how did `variants` property comes up to live? I don't have it defined in my `Product` class.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). It explains how you can use Eloquent's relations for this particular purpose. It explains more about the dynamic property given [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

This is designed to flawlessly be able to query on relationships, while also being able to quickly receive them.

As you said yourself:

- `variants()` returns the `hasMany` relation, which is just an addition on the query `Builder`. You use this when you want to query further on this relation:
  `Product::find(1)->variants()->where('quantity', '>', 0)->get()`
- `variants` returns the `Collection` instance just like if you had done `variants()->get()`, except you can continue to access this `Collection` from the `Product` `Model`, it won't re-call them from the database. When querying on this, you'll be querying on the [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction), not the query `Builder`.

Answer (score -1):

It's because `variant` is a dynamic property. You could achive something similar (simplified) this way:

```php
class Model
{
    public function dynamicProperty()
    {
        return 'dynamic value';
    }

    public function __get(string $property)
    {
        if ($property === 'dynamicProperty') {
            return $this->dynamicProperty();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, laravel does a lot more under the hood but `variant` is much like `variants()->get()` and `HasOne`/`HasMany`/`BelongsTo` is mostly a wrapper for `Builder`.