# How does Laravel resolve some methods in models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-relations

I wanna know how laravel can find and how it work some method like realtions method

(1:1 & 1:M )

---

for e.g in User Model i have one to many relation with My Post Model

```
public function posts(){
return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

and when i want to get some user posts data i will use this code

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->posts();
```

here is my question
**$user->posts();**
how laravel can find and reslove it

Comment: That is how the code works. `hasMany` tells the core how to do so... See the source code for [`hasMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php) and it extends [`HasOneOrMany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php). It is pure PHP... nothing fancy...

Comment: do you mean `$user->posts` without the parenthesis? because `$user->posts()` return a query builder instance and not the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937166/laravel-eloquent-relations-method-is-returning-hasmany-object-and-property-is/67937360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hasMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) is just one of the relationships that Eloquent provides for fluent querying to the database. With the correct column and table names, using these relationships, you can easily build a logical structure without having to dive into complex queries.

When you use a `hasMany`, Eloquent knows that the model you query on can have an n amount of related models, and will return a collection. It knows how to query using the model and method names. So, since your user has the `hasMany` for posts, Eloquent will query on `user_id` on the `posts` table.

For example, when you dump a query log on a `hasMany`, it will return the following:

`` select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1) ``

Eloquent will automatically append this to your model if you eager load it:
`User::with('posts')->find(1)`

I suggest reading the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) on relationships to figure out what Laravel and Eloquent assume to build queries.